# Binding Listbox value and Text in c# in aspx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a ListBox and want to bind value and text to it.

The Value and Text are taken from query string and they are comma separated.

My code goes as follows:

```
var pIDs = Request.QueryString["pIds"];
var pIDsText = Request.QueryString["pText"];
var SeparatedIds = pIDs.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
var SeparatedPIdsText = pIDsText.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();

System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox ls = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox)User_Control_ListBox1.FindControl("lstShowPrograms");

 for (int i = 0; i < SeparatedPIdsText.Length; i++)
 {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SeparatedPIdsText[i])) 
          {

                ls.Items.Add(SeparatedPIdsText[i]);
          }

 }
```

The above code is adding only text.I want to set both value and text.
Text to display and value(ID) for background.

Comment: Because you are looping and adding only text variable try a nested loop for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ListItem` to the `ls.Items` instead of `string`

```
ls.Items.Add(new ListItem(SeparatedPIdsText[i], SeparatedIds[i]));
```

Just make sure `SeparatedIds` and `SeparatedPIdsText` have the same length or there will be `IndexOutOfRangeException`